# gmap v2 -> v3 ( custom marker not showing + how to add the php address )

Tags: php, google-maps

Here is my v2 code that works ( marker didnt show )

```
<body onload="load()"> 

<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 520px; height: 370px"></div> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 

var userLocation = '<?php echo $address; ?>';
```

if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
   var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
   geocoder.getLocations(userLocation, function (locations) {
      if (locations.Placemark)
      {
         var north = locations.Placemark[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox.north;
         var south = locations.Placemark[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox.south;
         var east  = locations.Placemark[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox.east;
         var west  = locations.Placemark[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox.west;

```
     var bounds = new GLatLngBounds(new GLatLng(south, west), 
                                    new GLatLng(north, east));

     var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));

      var Icon = new GIcon();
      Icon.image = "images/422marker.png";
      Icon.iconSize = new GSize(33, 50);

     map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter(), map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds));
     map.addOverlay(new GMarker(bounds.getCenter()), Icon);
  }
```

});
}

Here is my v3 code ( marker does not show and not sure on how to utilise our php userLocation address scripting )

```
<body onload="load()">

<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 520px; height: 370px"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
var userLocation = '5th Avenue, New York';

var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 8,
  center: latlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

geocoder.geocode( { 'address': userLocation}, function(results, status) {

  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    // Geolocation was sucessfull

    // Set Marker Icon
    var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/422marker.png',
      new google.maps.Size(33,50),
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      new google.maps.Point(0,32));


    // Move map to position and set zoom
    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    map.setZoom(11);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: results[0].geometry.location,
      title: userLocation
      //icon: icon
      });
  } else {
    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
  }

});
```

So the issue I have is as folows:

v2 :

The custom marker didnt show , so updated map to v3

v3 :

The custom marker does not show + not sure how to use our php code to center the map on our coords , fetched from another script ( which worked in v2 )

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass the url for your custom image to icon key in the Marker initialisation

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  position: results[0].geometry.location,
  title: 'userLocation',
  icon: 'images/422marker.png'
});
```